# Dynamic file name in Maven archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I've problem with Maven. I tried to create archetype, but I don't now how to put source file to directory `${groupId}/${artifactId}`. If I try to create project from this archetype, file is stored implicitly in `${groupId}` directory. It seems Maven supposes, that group ID is a package name. But I'm using `${groupId}/${artifactId}` as package name so I need have the source file stored in `${groupId}/${artifactId}` directory. I have seen solution: to put the file into `__artifactId__` directory. Double underscore should determine a variable. However it doesn't take any effect. Variable seems to be empty, but in package name inside source file is used succesfully.

Have enybody idea, which trick shall have been done when using double underscore in file name?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have been trying to do the same thing, but with `__artifactId__` as a file name.  That is, `__artifactId__.java` contains `public class ${artifactId} {`, etc.  The substitution inside the file (i.e., ${artifactId}) works just fine, but the file name substitution does not.

Comment: Which version of the archetype plugin are you using? With version `maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0` the `__artifactId__.java` use case works just fine for me.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

When you create a archetype of your project like so:
`mvn archetype:create-from-project -Dinteractive`
Set the package - in an explicit form to the root of the project.

Then you create a project of this archetype enter your root package ${groupId}.$ {artifactId} in explicit form. example:
 `mvn archetype: generate
                         -DarchetypeGroupId = com.test
                         -DarchetypeArtifactId = my_archetype
                         -DgroupId = com.test
                         -DartifactId = app
                         -Dpackage = com.test.app
                         -Dversion = 1.0-SNAPHOT`

In this case, $ {groupId} = com.test, $ {artifactId} = app and **target package = com.test.app**

Comment: I don't see how this answers the original question of creating a dynamically named file much like dynamic directories.